# bash/ksh grep script take more than one argument

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

```
   #!/bin/ksh
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
    if grep -w -- "$1" codelist.lst
    then
        true
    else
        echo "Value not Found"
    fi
else
    echo "Please enter a valid input"
fi
```

This is my script and it works exactly how I want at the moment, I want to add if I add more arguments It will give me the multiple outputs, How can I do that?

So For Example I do ./test.sh apple it will grep apple in codelist.lst and Give me the output : Apple

**I want to do ./test.sh apple orange and will do:
Apple
Orange**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `shift` and a loop, something like (works in both `bash` and `ksh`):

```sh
for ((i = $#; i > 0 ; i--)) ; do
    echo "Processing '$1'"
    shift
done
```

You'll notice I've also opted *not* to use the `[[ -n "$1" ]]` method as that would terminate the loop early with an empty string (such as with `./script.sh a b "" c` stopping without doing `c`).

Comment: Can I combine if and for together? how it's like in my script? If value found = echo value, If nothing inserted as an argument, Please insert value, If value not found echo value not found

I did this:

for ((i = $#; i > 0 ; i--)) ; do
    grep -w -- "$1" codelist.lst || echo "'$1' not found"
    shift
done

But how can i do else echo "Please enter a value"

Comment: @user1543961, you can check `$#` for zero before entering the for loop. But I see you've asked that as a separate question so I'll go and answer it there :-)

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the *positional parameters*:

```sh
for pattern in "$@"; do
  grep -w -- "$pattern" codelist.lst || echo "'$pattern' not Found"
done
```

For a more advanced usage, which only invokes grep once, use the `-f` option with a shell process substitution:

```sh
grep -w -f <(printf '%s\n' "$@") codelist.lst
```

Comment: You don't need `-f <(...)`; grep's _argument_ can be multiple patterns separated by newline `grep -we "$(printf '%s\n' "$@")"` or more trickily `IFS=$'\n'; grep -we "$*"`